# Cocos2d: how to make a drawn circle doing scale or fade out animation

Tags: animation, cocos2d-iphone, draw

I know how to draw a circle in cocos2d & I know how to do cocos2d animation (scale and fade) with a ccsprite(loaded from a png file).

But I am wondering is it possible to store a drawn circle(in draw function) somehow and do animation with it just we normally do with ccsprite.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the inner workings of your animations and you should be able to piece together the rest.

Take a look at `CCScaleTo` for example. If you look at its `update:` function, all it does is change the scale of the CCNode it links to over time.

You should make your circle by extending `CCSprite` (or `CCNode`) and overriding the `draw` function. Here you can just call `super` to handle the translation or if you need a bit more control, you should modify your translation matrix yourself to take the position, rotation, scale into account (e.g. `glScalef(x, y, z)`) with OpenGLES.

```
-(void) draw
{
    [super draw];
    //Your draw code for the circle.
}
```

Comment: that sounds like what I need. Would this new class extending CCSprite work with z order ? E.g. NewClass:CCSprite{...}; NewClass myCircle; [self addChild:myCircle z:10]; The z order of the new circle should have a z order of 10 right ?